# Using VBA to save a file in excel 2010 with a different name each time

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, save-as

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using as a template to get user input. When you press the submit button on the spreadsheet, it sends the data to a different workbook that stores all the previous entries and then clears the template. Is there a way to save the template as a different file when you push the button? I know about .Saveas(), but I want a file name that's based off what was typed in cell A2 and B2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this on a daily basis saving the file as the previous days date. I modified what I use for what you are wanting:

```
dim name as string

name = Cells(1,2).Value & Cells(2,2).Value

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs() Filename:=name
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be simple. I just couldn't think of how to do it. Thank you!