# Save a file with a name that corresponds to a cell value

Tags: excel, vba

Background: I'm working with a macro that transfers data between different workbooks. One of the workbooks is a conduit for data and doesn't change. The other workbook is a blank form that is populated, saved as a specific name and then reused.

Problem: The workbook being saved needs to use the contents of a cell in the conduit workbook for it's name.

I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21897456/using-vba-to-save-a-file-in-excel-2010-with-a-different-name-each-time). The answer gives me a syntax error.

```
Sub TestTestTestTest()
'
' TestTestTestTest Macro
'

'
    Dim name As String
    name = Cells("Contents", A1)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs() Filename:=name**********
End Sub
```

The starred line is the source of the syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered the file path? or which workbook you are getting A1 from?

I assume Contents is a sheet and A1 is the filename ( for future people looking at this Contents was not the sheet)

```
Dim name As String
name = range("A1").value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=name
```

just for your knowledge to do the same with cells you can use

```
cells(1,1).value
```

Cells expects numerical values for column/row

To point to a sheet you can use

```
sheets("sheet1").range("A1").value
sheets("sheet1").cells(1,1).value
```

You could shorten this whole thing by using

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=range("A1").value
```

Comment: Cell("Contents",A1) Returns the contents of cell A1, not my sheet name.

Comment: cells will never work like that. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567.aspx

Comment: Ahhh, was looking at the formula, not the VBA code https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/CELL-function-51bd39a5-f338-4dbe-a33f-955d67c2b2cf

Comment: ahhh. range("A1").value without the sheet ref will give you the contents of A1 on the activesheet. I have amended the above answer slightly

Comment: Is there any way to use two cells to name the file? For example the contents of A1 underscore contents of A2?

Comment: name = range("A1").value & "_" & range("A2").value you can concatenate as much as you like using &.

Comment: Thank you so much! I regret that I have but one upvote to give.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove brackets:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=name
```

Or if you want to use bracket, you need to put parameters inside them and add keyword `Call` at the beginning:

```
Call ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename:=name)
```